# PHP Function with parameters to return different strings

Tags: php, function, variables, parameters

**
After the first answer: 5 year old project that needs to be updated

My problem is that at the moment one single product-download page has at least 14 functions and over 1200 lines of code. I basically just want to make it more simple to make changes and decrease the file size and code e.g. add all vars at the top of the page and not having to search thru the entire code to find where they have to be added and cut out as many dupicate functions as possible ...
**

Some of the vars (all with extra functions) for the same object:

```
 $p1_files = "'p-1.zip', 'p-2.zip', 'p-3.zip', 'p-4.zip', 'p-5.zip'";
 $p2_files = "'p2-1.zip', 'p2-2.zip', 'p2-3.zip', 'p2-4.zip', 'p2-5.zip'";
 $p3_files = "'p3-1.zip', 'p3-download-2.zip', 'p3-download-3.zip', 'p3-4.zip', 'p3-5.zip'";
```

the "very shortend" function:

```
 function p_files_function(){
    $p1_files = "'p-1.zip', 'p-2.zip', 'p-3.zip', 'p-4.zip', 'p-5.zip'";
    return $p1_files; 
 }
```

the "p_files_function()" returns

```
 'p-1.zip', 'p-2.zip', 'p-3.zip', 'p-4.zip', 'p-5.zip'
```

which is perfect and I can use to create the listings but it only works with 1 var.

Now, what I would like to do is to add all vars to one function and only return the needed one
 Something like

```
// List all vars at top of page
    $p1_files = "'p-1.zip', 'p-2.zip', 'p-3.zip', 'p-4.zip', 'p-5.zip'";
    $p2_files = "'p2-1.zip', 'p2-2.zip', 'p2-3.zip', 'p2-4.zip', 'p2-5.zip'";
    $p3_files = "'p3-1.zip', 'p3-download-2.zip', 'p3-download-3.zip', 'p3-4.zip', 'p3-5.zip'";
// one function to get the needed vars 
 function p_files_function($args){
 if Value1 {
    $needed_files = $p1_files
        }
 if Value2 {
    $needed_files = $p2_files
        }
 if Value3 {
    $needed_files = $p3_files
        }
    return $needed_files; 
    }

// easy way to get the needed vars 
 p_files_function(Value2) //should retuns $p2_files
```

any ideas?

- This is very shortend there are also images, documents and so on, I managed to cut everything else down to minimum but with this I am lost, all I need is a starting point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think adding the suffix _function to your function name is a little redundant. That said:

```
function p_files($type) {

   switch ($type) {
      case 'p1': 
          return "'p-1.zip', 'p-2.zip', 'p-3.zip', 'p-4.zip', 'p-5.zip'";
      case 'p2': 
          return "'p2-1.zip', 'p2-2.zip', 'p2-3.zip', 'p2-4.zip', 'p2-5.zip'";
      case 'p3': 
          return "'p3-1.zip', 'p3-download-2.zip', 'p3-download-3.zip', 'p3-4.zip', 'p3-5.zip'";
      default: 
          return ''; // or trigger error or whatever
   }

}

$needed_files = p_files('p1'); // etc
```

Comment: ok, so what would you do instead? my problem is that at the moment one single product download page has at least 14 functions and over 1200 lines of code. I basically just want to make it more simple to make changes and maybe decrease the file size and code e.g. add new file-names at the top of the page and not searching thru the entire code to find where they have to be added and cut out as many dupicatefunctions as possible ...

Comment: I would try to recognize a pattern in the filenames and abstract the logic to a class named FileFinder or so. Also, consider storing data in a database if that is an option. Looks like there's a lot of data in your code.